# How to prevent user sending requests frequently?

Tags: magento2, php, javascript, requirejs, cookie

I believe it can be done with a PHP controller or JS cookie manipulation.
Help me with logic. For example, I want a user to send a request once every 2 minutes.

Let's pretend I've implemented some logic in the PHP controller and when I click the form Submit button in a custom product view tab, it says "You have already submitted a request in the past 2 minutes. Please try again later"

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Using PHP**
In the controller, Insert the current date and time into the `cookie`.

If the user clicks on the submit button the first time set the `cookie` and the second time check `cookie` is set or not.

If the `cookie` sets and compares the `current date` time with the `cookie` date time is greater than 2 minus the perform the action otherwise returns an error message.

**2. Using jQuery**

Logic same as PHP controller. In jQuery use localStorage to set current data and time for the compare.

```
Set current date into localStorage
var currentTime = new Date();


localStorage.setItem('storage', currentTime);   

Get date from localStorage
var get_date = localStorage.getItem('storage');
console.log(get_date);

Compare the current date and storage date to write your logic. 
If the condition is not fulfilled, Disable the submit button.
```